# P25 Digital vs. Analog

Tags: digital-voice, motorola, p25

Recently, I was given a [Motorola XTS 5000](https://www.motorolasolutions.com/en_us/products/two-way-radios/project-25-radios/discontinued/xts-5000.html) (Model 1) [P25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_25) radio to play around with.  It has several local repeaters already programmed into it.  It is set for "Mixed Mode", which will receive either a P25 digital signal or analog.  All the local repeaters are also set for Mixed Mode.

Given that I can receive digital or analog, via a repeater that will pass digital or analog, from a transmitting station that can transmit digital or analog, and vice versa, what is the benefit to P25? What does P25 give me that my normal analog HT won't besides the ability to transmit digitally?  Why would I want to?

---

**Update:** I understand that the P25 standard offers a substantial feature set that is very powerful.  My question is more geared to the scenario where several hams are hanging out on the local repeater rag chewing.  In that case, is there any benefit to using P25 over analog?  In my limited experience, the voice quality seemed slightly inferior so I don't think there is anything to be gained there. Is there something else that I am missing?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64993/discussion-on-question-by-lance-p25-digital-vs-analog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only differentiator between digital v analog that I can come up with in your scenario is: the effective distance for **clear** communication is increased... if I can get into the repeater, I'll have the same signal quality as someone standing next to the tower antenna.

The effective distance for **intelligible** communication is decreased... the human ear/brain combo can decipher a voice in the static surprisingly well. With digital communication, there's more of a stark distance cliff after which, there's no chance.

Both analog and digital systems can fire up some kind of VOIP on the backend to interconnect distant repeaters (echolink, P25 TGs) so it's not really a differentiator IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to give comparison between your color tv and smart tv when try to relates analog /digital legacy radio communications and introduction of  P25 standards. Like any  smart TV P25 gives lots of advantage over legacy system.

Among all other benefits of P25 standards adoption specifically on public safety communication, interoperability and efficiency of spectrum usability stand on top and visible to any party.

P25 is adaptation of standardization of radio communications among various types of users for their communication needs. Before P25 era every other organizations have their own way of planing and implementation of  radio communications practice which is troublesome for quick interoperability needs. Also other features like user control, authorization, encryption makes robust communication experience both for admission and general user.

You can get a real picture by visiting this wiki pages on P25 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_25

Comment: Thanks.  I added some additional information to my question to hopefully clarify what I'm actually asking.